'NXOpen.BlockStyler.PropertyList' does not contain a definition for 'SetStringList'
I tried based on ChatGPT to create in drawing a list of sheet format that let user choose in one click:

This code should update the drawing automatically , example from A0 to 3A0 . But the code give the error message bellow . ==> the main idea is when the user want to modify the size of the sheet, just click on the new size and the code run the update automatically.
I am running on .NET Framework 4.8 (update 528372) and using the integrated journal editor from Unigraphics NX.
Line 225 : 'NXOpen.BlockStyler.PropertyList' does not contain a definition for 'SetStringList' and no extension method 'SetStringList' accepting a first argument of type 'NXOpen.BlockStyler.PropertyList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Line 264 : ) expected
Line 264 : ; expected
Line 264 : Invalid expression term ')'
Line 264 : ; expected
Line 264 : Invalid expression term ')'

Here is the complete code:
using System;
using NXOpen;
using NXOpen.BlockStyler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
  
public class sDrawing_Size
{
    private static Session theSession = null;
    private static UI theUI = null;
    private string theDlxFileName;
    private NXOpen.BlockStyler.BlockDialog theDialog;
    private NXOpen.BlockStyler.Group group0;
    private NXOpen.BlockStyler.ListBox list_box0;

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Tuple<double, double>> DrawingSizes = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<double, double>>
    {
        { "A0", new Tuple<double, double>(841, 1189) },
        { "A1", new Tuple<double, double>(594, 841) },
        { "A2", new Tuple<double, double>(420, 594) },
        { "A3", new Tuple<double, double>(297, 420) },
        { "A4", new Tuple<double, double>(210, 297) },
        { "2A0", new Tuple<double, double>(1189 * 2, 841) },
    };
        
    public sDrawing_Size()
    {
        try
        {
            theSession = Session.GetSession();
            theUI = UI.GetUI();
            theDlxFileName = "C:\\Users\\iennadif\\Desktop\\NX_BLOCK_STYLER\\Drawing_Size.dlx";
            theDialog = theUI.CreateDialog(theDlxFileName);
            theDialog.AddApplyHandler(new NXOpen.BlockStyler.BlockDialog.Apply(apply_cb));
            theDialog.AddOkHandler(new NXOpen.BlockStyler.BlockDialog.Ok(ok_cb));
            theDialog.AddUpdateHandler(new NXOpen.BlockStyler.BlockDialog.Update(update_cb));
            theDialog.AddInitializeHandler(new NXOpen.BlockStyler.BlockDialog.Initialize(initialize_cb));
            theDialog.AddDialogShownHandler(new NXOpen.BlockStyler.BlockDialog.DialogShown(dialogShown_cb));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        sDrawing_Size thesDrawing_Size = null;
        try
        {
            thesDrawing_Size = new sDrawing_Size();
            thesDrawing_Size.Launch();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Block Styler", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Error, ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if(thesDrawing_Size != null)
            {
                thesDrawing_Size.Dispose();
                thesDrawing_Size = null;
            }
        }
    }
 
     public static int GetUnloadOption(string arg)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToInt32(Session.LibraryUnloadOption.Immediately);
    }
    
    public static void UnloadLibrary(string arg)
    {
        try
        {
            // Add any cleanup code here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Block Styler", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Error, ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    
    public NXOpen.BlockStyler.BlockDialog.DialogResponse Launch()
    {
        try
        {
            return theDialog.Launch();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Block Styler", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Error, ex.ToString());
            return NXOpen.BlockStyler.BlockDialog.DialogResponse.Cancel;
        }
    }
    

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(theDialog != null)
        {
            theDialog.Dispose();
            theDialog = null;
        }
    }

    
    public void initialize_cb()
{
    try
    {
        group0 = (NXOpen.BlockStyler.Group)theDialog.TopBlock.FindBlock("group0");
        list_box0 = (NXOpen.BlockStyler.ListBox)theDialog.TopBlock.FindBlock("list_box0");

        NXOpen.BlockStyler.PropertyList listBoxProps = list_box0.GetProperties();
        
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        foreach (var size in DrawingSizes.Keys)
        {
            items.Add(size); // Add sizes to the list
        }

        listBoxProps.SetStringList("ListItems", items.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Block Styler", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Error, ex.ToString());
    }
}

   public void dialogShown_cb()
    {
        // Add any pre-dialog launch logic here
    }
    

     public int apply_cb()
    {
    try
    {
        NXOpen.BlockStyler.PropertyList listBoxProps = list_box0.GetProperties();
        
        // Assuming "SelectedItems" is a valid property name for the ListBox
        var selectedItems = listBoxProps.GetStringList("SelectedItems");

        if (selectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            string selectedSize = selectedItems[0]; // Get the first selected item

            if (DrawingSizes.TryGetValue(selectedSize, out var size))
            {
                double width = size.Item1;
                double height = size.Item2;

                // Add logic to set the drawing size in NX here
                theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Drawing Size Updated", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Information, 
                    "Width: " + width + " mm, Height: " + height + " mm");
            }
            else
            {
                theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Error", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Error, "Invalid drawing size selected.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Error", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Error, "No drawing size selected.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Block Styler", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Error, ex.ToString());
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

    public int update_cb(NXOpen.BlockStyler.UIBlock block)
    {
        try
        {
            if(block == list_box0)
            {
                // Add any update logic for list_box0 here
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Block Styler", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Error, ex.ToString());
        }
        return 0;
    }
    

    public int ok_cb()
    {
        return apply_cb();
    }

     public PropertyList GetBlockProperties(string blockID)
    {
        try
        {
            return theDialog.GetBlockProperties(blockID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Block Styler", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Error, ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Here is the error according the line in the main code:
listBoxProps.SetStringList("ListItems", items.ToArray());

NXOpen.BlockStyler.PropertyList' does not contain a definition for 'SetStringList' and no extension method 'SetStringList' accepting a first argument of type 'NXOpen.BlockStyler.PropertyList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

if (DrawingSizes.TryGetValue(selectedSize, out var size))

: ) expected
: ; expected
: Invalid expression term ')'
: ; expected
: Invalid expression term ')'
: ; expected

else


: Invalid expression term 'else'
: ; expected


Your problem seems to be that NXOpen.BlockStyler.PropertyList does not have a method SetStringList.  However, according to the NXOpen .NET documentation found here, it does have these methods:

public void SetStrings(string propertyName, string[] stringArray)

public string[] GetStrings(string propertyName)


So you should use those methods:
var selectedItems = listBoxProps.GetStrings("SelectedItems");

And
listBoxProps.SetStrings("ListItems", items.ToArray());

In addition, if you are getting a compilation error for if (DrawingSizes.TryGetValue(selectedSize, out var size)), that suggests your C# language version is less than version 7 which introduced the out var syntax.  If so, you will need to declare your size variable explicitly:
Tuple<double, double> size;
if (DrawingSizes.TryGetValue(selectedSize, out size))
{
    double width = size.Item1;
    double height = size.Item2; 

Alternatively you could try to update your C# language version, since .NET Framework 4.8 shipped with C# 7.3.  To do that in Visual Studio, see .NET Framework 4.8 seems to use C# version older than 7.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do that in the integrated journal editor.
Finally, while this is not a compilation error, I note that your sDrawing_Size type has a Dispose() method.  In such cases you should make your type implement the Dispose pattern then dispose of it via a using statement:
public class sDrawing_Size : IDisposable
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var thesDrawing_Size = new sDrawing_Size())
        {
            try
            {
                thesDrawing_Size.Launch();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                theUI.NXMessageBox.Show("Block Styler", NXMessageBox.DialogType.Error, ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(theDialog != null)
        {
            theDialog.Dispose();
            theDialog = null;
        }
    }
    

You might also want to follow C# identifier naming conventions, e.g. sDrawing_Size might better be in Pascal case: SDrawingSize.

Note: I don't have Unigraphics currently available to test this answer.
